# Find whether a pattern of pair of numbers will repeat

Tags: number-theory

**Note: Not sure if I chose the appropriate tag**

I have a problem where I have a pair of numbers e.g. (10000, 0).

The pair initializes with the first number being larger than the second (second always initializes to zero).

Both number have a max limit; either number in the pair cannot exceed 65000. When a number tries exceeding its limit, it is reset to 0.

Once the pair is initialized, the number are increased as follows:

- everytime first number inc by 1, second number inc by 1
- second number can keep increasing if needed, without first number increasing

As time progresses, the first number increases every 30 seconds. Within a 30 second time interval, the number of times the second number is increased is not fixed. 
**Edit:** the second number can increase a random number of times within a 30 second period. Its not fixed. So when a new 30 second slot comes about, increase second number by 1. Then pick a random number >= zero, and increase the second number by that amount. **To the reader: if it makes easier for you assume that the second number can increased by an amount 0 to 500 (in addition to its increment by 1 due to first number increase).**

My question is that whether there is a a way to find whether the numbers the pair was initialized with will ever repeat, i.e. will the pair be ever set to (10000, 0) again ?

Comment: It's not clear to me when the second number increases. Can you explain more what causes the second number to increase?

Comment: Okay I'll edit the question

Comment: The number of times the second number is increased is not fixed? Then it might repeat, or it might not.  It's easy to construct scenarios for both.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. You could make the second number increase arbitrarily quickly or slowly. So if first number is 10000 in a particular 30 second interval, you can make second number 0 in same (or next interval - if time is discrete and first number is incremented at the very last instant of interval).

Comment: @Χpẘ:  it isn't about fast or slow, it is about common factors with $65000$

Comment: @Ross the rate of the second number (before the edit) isn't fixed and could reasonably be expected to be controllable (that's not the case after the edit though). In which case making the second number increment fast enough will give 0 within a interval in which first number becomes 10000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With probability $1$ the pair $(10000,0)$ will repeat unless there is something special about the increases of the second number.  The first will repeat with a period $65000 \cdot 30$ seconds and will stay at each value for $30$ seconds.  We might as well define $30$ seconds as a period.  In that case the first number is $10000$ once every $65000$ periods.  If the number of increments of the second number rattles around enough, it will eventually be $0$ in the same period when the first is $10000$.  This can fail if the number of increments of the second is $21$ in the first period then $13$ in every period thereafter.  The second will hit $0$ every $5000$ periods, but never when the first is at $10000$.  If there is reasonable randomness to the second increments you can avoid the periodicity and eventually $(10000,0)$ will repeat.  As I have shown, probability $1$ does not mean the opposite is impossible, just that over a long time the probability of the opposite is as small as you want.

Comment: I made a small edit to the question.

Comment: @Jake:  as long as the increment of the second number is random, my argument holds.  Note that an increment of $13$ is within the range you specified.  If there is a periodicity that makes sure $(10000,0)$ doesn't repeat, we are done.  If not, with probability $1$ it will.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the periodicity part ? You mention that it would make sure the pattern would not repeat.

Comment: @Jake:  in my example with an increment of $13$ the second will go through $0$ every $5000$ periods, but they are chosen (by my first increment of $21$) to avoid the periods where the first is $10000$.  You could specify a series of increments to the second number that vary but avoid going through $0$ when the first number is $10000$.